# Reactive Native - custom iOS module with pod dependency

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios

I need to create react native ios module which intern uses cocopod.

I tried creating static library which had podfile and created workspace. In my main react project i have added my static library ,but i am unable to add those dependencies of pod in my main project . I am stuck here.

I am having two questions,

1. What would be the best way to create react native modules (which doesnt have any UI components). Does it need to be static library or any other project template to be choose?
2. If static library is the best option , then how do i have dependency with pods and integrate the module with main project?

**Note :** I tried creating module.podspec file and tried installing pod from main project. But i am unable to install my framework's dependency.

Pod installation goes like this. 
MainReactProject -> MainReactProject.podfile (this refers) -> module.podspec(added as s.depandacy "somespec")->somespec.podspec.

During this execution, 
I am getting error as unable to find specification for 'somespec